# New userControl in Page_Load doesn't have CSS in Webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls

In a page I added a new userControl in the Page_Load, but when I load the page, I see my control but the CSS is broken, it's shown as a simple textbox without my CSS.

Here is the code:

```
if (Contexte.GetLanguage == "UK")
{
    UC_DooFinder = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/inc/DooFinder.ascx");
    UC_DooFinder.ID = "UC_DOOFINDER";
    this.Controls.Add(UC_DooFinder);
    UC_Recherche.Dispose();
}
```

"this" is a page called "Header.ascx", which is included in my master page.

But if I include the userControl in the front it works.
But I need to call it from the .cs for some reasons.

Comment: It should not matter if you add a UC programmatically or in the aspx. Are you perhaps applying css on ID's rather that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution : I initialize my userControls in the page_init event and it works fine now.

Thanks.